# How to create a new measure that subtracts two filters of the same variable?

Tags: matrix, filter, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

On PowerBI, I'm working on creating a matrix table that contains rows of `stores`, columns of `years`, and values called `percentages`. There are two filters of `years`, 2022 and 2021. each column contains a percentage for each year. So, for example:

```
     Store | 2021 | 2022 | Diff
    Target | 42%  | 40%  | -2%
   Walmart | 45%  | 48%  |  3%
```

So basically, I used `Filters` to get the values of 2022 and 2021. Now, I want to create a new measure that calculates `Diff` which is the difference between the years. However, I cannot figure out a way to find the difference between two filters of the same variable `years`. Right now, the matrix gives me the total, which is not what I want.

Edit: here are some illustrating pictures. The blanks in 2022 should have a diff of 0%
[image: matrix picture]
[image: rows and cols of matrix]
[image: Date hierarchy in Fields]
[image: Filters of years]

Comment: There will be always 2 year? Years are dynamic like current and previous year?

Comment: Please post sample data and your measures.

Comment: @mkRabbani right now, I am selecting 2021 and 2022 out of 3 years from the filters section as added in the pictures, but ideally i want it to select current and previous year. I added more details and pictures above

Comment: @David I just added more pictures and details

Comment: @RSB Then Matrix is not a good way to visualize your data. Stick with simple table and create 2 measure - one for current year percentage and another one for previous year percentage.  Finally the difference is simply Measure1 - Measure2.

Comment: What is the DAX syntax for creating a measure that contains a filter (since 2021 is a filter of the variable 'year')? @mkRabbani